# python falcon falcon.before with async

Tags: python, python-3.x, falconframework, falcon

I'm looking to add a `falcon.before` hook such as:

```
def check_authenticated(request, response, resource, params):
    print(request.headers)
    request.context.test = 'test'

@falcon.before(check_authenticated)
class testing(object):
    async def on_get(self, request, response):
        print(request.headers)
        print('made it here')
```

But I keep facing the error: `TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

Answer (score 0):

By the asynchronous signature (`async def`) of your `on_get` responder, I assume that you're using the ASGI flavour of the framework.
In that case, not only your responders, but also middleware methods, hooks, sinks, error handler functions must be awaitable coroutine functions.

Compare and contrast the WSGI and ASGI versions of this ["more complex example"](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#a-more-complex-example), where a hook is applied with [`falcon.before`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/hooks.html#falcon.before) in both synchronous and asynchronous flavours of the framework.

TL;DR you need to change your hook to `async def check_authenticated(...)`.